# editing XAML textbox not from MainPage class

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, windows-phone

I have the MainPage class which I can edit the contents of the XAML textbox from using this code

```
box1.Text = "";
```

however trying to edit the textbox from another class the following code will do not work

```
MainPage.box1.Text = "";
```

The error is "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'class.MainPage.box1'
I have tried everything like making static functions and creating new MainPage objects in the other class but nothing has worked

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Alex, is this WPF or Silverlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XAML Textbox is in MainPage.xaml/.cs

Your value setter for the Textbox is in some class X.

The reason for your error on below statement is, the box1 is not static and you need an instance of the MainPage.

```
MainPage.box1.Text = "";
```

But not just any instance. You need the current instance. So the method in the class X, needs to receive a "THIS" instance of MainPage.xaml.cs class and then change the box1 value.

The function call:

```
X xobj=new X();
xobj.ChangeboxValue(this);
```

The function:

```
void ChangeboxValue(MainPage obj)
{
obj.box1.Text=""
}
```

Comment: Thanks! very clear description of how it all works and I got it working now

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a static field of the `MainPage` class without an object instance.

You'll need an instance of the `MainPage` class to access it like this:

```
MainPage myPage = new MainPage();
myPage.box1.Text = "";
```

Comment: i tried this, the app crashes with invalid cross thread access. when putting your code inside Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=> the app doesnt crash but the textbox is not edited

Comment: It would probably be helpful to include some more context in your sample code, then.