# Set Text to a TextBox from different file.xaml.cs Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

How to set a Text to a TextBox from another file.xaml.cs in Windows Phone?
In my case, I have a class.xaml.cs that will set a Text for anotherClass.xaml.cs. I still don't get how to set it.

Comment: [SOLVED]
Viewing this answer :)
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314066/editing-xaml-textbox-not-from-mainpage-class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314066/editing-xaml-textbox-not-from-mainpage-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hy,

taking into account that on WindowsPhone can display a page at a time, you can do it in different ways, either by passing parameters between pages when you run the method NavigationService, or variables declared in the App class, which remains alive until the application not be completed, or with a static class and you create the / properties that you need, for more details see this thread

[Passing a string between pages in Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223924/passing-a-string-between-pages-in-windows-phone-8)